# Strategies to improve spoken English and vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary

Would learning 10 new words per day and then using it more often help in using this language more effectively? I believe it would also construct a more extensive library of vocabulary which is too a plus point.

Is this an effective one or would there be better alternatives?

Comment: There is a difference between reading the words and speaking the words. Talk with anyone who will listen. Make mistakes. Accept feedback gracefully. You must live the language.

Comment: That is true, since learning a word and its meaning would also require to be used in a proper sentence in a proper way. Gotta live it, indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good. It could help a little bit. The time will come when you need those words you learn. I did it myself before. You can even learn more than 10 words a day. But it's also more important to know how to use those words.

I suggest you consider those learning methods too because they were the most effective for me:

1. Practice. Whenever you have a chance to speak English, do it.
2. Listen a lot. Movies, podcasts, TV shows, Speeches, etc.
3. Read. From time to time you'll need to google something. Search
   in English. also find interesting topics for you and read about them
   in  English.
4. Translate. This technique was also good for me. I was a member in a
   football(Soccer) forum. I used to look for sports news in known
   sites and then translate it to my first language. It took time and
   effort actually as my wasn't very good but it was very helpful.

When practicing those, the words you learn will absolutely come up from time to time and you will know how to use them correctly.

Finally, I'm not sure I'm suggesting something new for you. Your English doesn't seem bad at all.

Good luck.

Comment: Love how you mentioned my idea is good but said, could help a little bit right afterwards, haha. That is true, one must learn how to use the word after knowing the word itself and its meaning. I intend to reach the expertise of native speaker so that I am more expressive and eloquent in my speech/context.The answer was overall elaborated and precise. Thank you and thank you once again for the compliment.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding vocabulary is important in learning English Language. However, it's pointless to just memorizing them without the understanding of how each word and how they are used in a sentence.

You can:

1. Write down the words you have learned - make a synonym list for each word
2. Learn the lyrics of English songs - pay attention to how the singer pronounce the words and stressing on different sounds, try to sing along too!
3. Play word games